# Google Calendar is Not Syncing with Gmail Meeting Invitations

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google-calendar

I am having an issue where Google email (Gmail) meeting invitations are not syncing with my Google Calendar.

Example, I get an meeting notification in email, and when I accept, it's not showing on Google Calendar. Or sometimes I see it, but it disappears from the calendar a few days later.

Anyone experienced this issue, and how to fix it?

Note: This is occurring multiple times for many meetings, and meetings are not removed from the organizer)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If Google Calendar is not syncing with Gmail meeting invitations, there are a few steps you can take to troubleshoot and resolve the issue:

Check your [Google Calendar settings](https://xfanatical.com/blog/how-to-recover-emails-from-gmail/): Ensure that your Google Calendar settings are configured correctly. Go to your Google Calendar, click on the gear icon in the top right corner, and select "Settings." Verify that the "Events from Gmail" option is enabled under the "Events" section.

Clear cache and cookies: Clearing cache and cookies can often resolve syncing issues. Open your browser's settings, find the option to clear browsing data, and select to clear cache and cookies. Restart your browser afterward and try accessing Google Calendar again.

Check your Google account settings: Make sure that your Google account is set up properly to sync Gmail and Calendar. Go to your Google Account settings by clicking on your profile picture in the top right corner of any Google page and selecting "Google Account." Navigate to the "Data & personalization" section and ensure that the relevant settings for Gmail and Calendar are enabled.

Check for conflicting browser extensions: Some browser extensions can interfere with the syncing process. Disable any extensions that may be causing conflicts, particularly ones related to calendar or email management. Try accessing Google Calendar again after disabling the extensions.

Update your browser: Ensure that your browser is up to date with the latest version. Outdated browser versions can sometimes lead to compatibility issues with Google services. Check for updates in your browser's settings and install any available updates.

Comment: Chatgpt strikes again.